# 'enclosing' scopes for friendship classes

Tags: c++, scope

Bjarne Stroustrup writes:

"a friend class must be previously declared in an enclosing scope or defined in the non-class scope immediately enclosing the class that is declaring it a friend"

Isn't the first part of the statement redundant, because the "non-class scope immediately enclosing the class " includes "previously declared in an enclosing scope"? IE:, what is the difference in these two scopes?

Comment: "a friend class must be previously declared" - sounds weird. It's perfectly valid to say `struct A { friend class B; };` without having `B` previously declared.

Comment: AFAIK you can declare *any* class to be a friend: struct A {friend classDNE;}. I think here Bjarne is talking about how the class in the friend declaration statement 'binds' to the definition (if one exists). So in your case if B was defined in global space, and A was defined in a namespace, the friend class 'B' in A's declaration would not 'bind' to the global class B - the global class B would not be able to access A's private members.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the first part, the friend class is declared inside a class (nested) that declares it a friend. While in the second part, the friend class is declared outside, just before the class that declared it a friend.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that the second part says "immediately enclosing" and the first one does not? So I gather from it that if the class is declared in a non-class scope (i.e. namespace or global), it can be only the immediately enclosing scope (one up). If it's declared in an enclosing *class* scope (think nested classes), it can be as much above as you want.

Meaning the following is valid:

```
class Grandpa
{
    class Mother
    {
        class Junior
        {
            friend class Grandpa;
        };

    };
};
```

Just because `Grandpa` is several "class scopes" above `Junior`.

Comment: I think you might be onto something but it's hard to make sure given that the language is (inherently) imprecise. The bit that threw me off was "a friend class must be previously declared in an enclosing scope ". If you declare (which AFAIK is the same as define when talking about classes) a friend class in the global scope (which encloses *all* scopes), it doesn't work.

Comment: alas, English is a much more ambiguous language than c++ :-)

Answer (score -1):

Friends don't let friends use friends.

Comment: Rather, friends have access to your private members, which is something you generally don't want.

Comment: It's funny because it's true.